# FFmpeg/nvenc(cuda): Where is the documentation for h264_nvenc encoder?

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, nvenc, nvidia

I'm trying to use Nvidia's h264_nvenc video encoder with ffmpeg but I can't find a single source of documentation for it. I want to know what options are supported and what they do.

The software libx264 encoder has good documentation: http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264

But I can't find the equivalent for h264_nvenc.

There is a little bit of information on
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro and
https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/nvidia-ffmpeg-transcoding-guide/ but these seem to just contain examples, whereas I'm looking for more of a reference for what the encoder can do. Thanks

Comment: Run `ffmpeg -h encoder=h264_nvenc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavcodec/nvenc.h#L186-L221

and the valid can be referenced from https://github.com/FFmpeg/nv-codec-headers/blob/master/include/ffnvcodec/nvEncodeAPI.h